# Installing gwt Eclipse plugin I get the error No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I have Eclipse Luna Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)

And I'm trying to install the GWT plugin for Eclipse from here

https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.4

But when I click "Finish" in the end of the installation process I get a pop-up with the following error

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.core,3.14.0.v20140930-2139
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.screenshots,3.14.0.v20140929-1821
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui,3.14.0.v20140929-1821
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.workbench,3.14.0.v20140929-1821
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.aspectj.runtime.source,1.7.0.20120703164200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.contribution.xref.core.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.contribution.xref.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.contribution.xref.ui.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons,3.14.0.v20140930-2139
```

I tried to follow this comment

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=290782#c2

and I manged to succesfully uninstall the Eclipse Project Update, but I can't re-install it through the link given by the author of the comment, nor I'm able to install the GWT plugin, so now  I'm really stuck with this problem.

Anyone can figure out what to do next to get rid of this situation?

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same problem.
If you go into:

> window->preferences->Install/Update->Available Software Sites

Then, at the bottom of the list you will see several unchecked options.  If you select the one labelled `"Mylyn 3.14 for Eclipse 3.8, 4.3 and 4.4   http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/3.14"`, and then select enabled, and apply.
Then, go back and try installing the gwt plugin, it should work. (it did for me)

**Note:**
I'm guessing that this *might* only be a temporary problem where the `"Mylyn 3.14 for Eclipse 3.8, 4.3 and 4.4  http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest"` just isn't listing the correctly available options, but we shall see.

Answer (score 0):

I had select all repositories in window->preferences->Install/Update->Available Software Sites.

Repository ["Mylyn 3.14 for Eclipse 3.8, 4.3 and 4.4 http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/3.14"] was already selected.